# Supporting ABP's IEntityCache for entities with multi-column primary keys

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

The current implementation of [IEntityCache](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp/Domain/Entities/Caching/EntityCache.cs)  supports a 1-column primary key type (default `int`, can be sent as a different type, e.g. `long`, `string`).

Currently there are 2 approaches (that I can see) to enable caching for tables/entities whose primary key consists of 2 (or more) columns, such as 2 string columns:

1. Modify the schema of the table and simply add an integer Id column (auto-increment) whose sole purpose is to enable the `IEntityCache` to do its magic. The application logic querying the entity would remain untouched as it would still use the 2-column unique index. Modifying the schema however may not be an option, and another problem is that the upper application layers (Domain, AppServices) are not aware of the Id they need to query, instead they are aware of the entity's 2 keys.
2. Rewrite a new implementation of IEntityCache to support multiple columns (e.g. `IEntityCache<string, string>`?). Not sure if this is even feasible given the cachemanager's limitations?

Here's the question: Would the inner workings of the `ICacheManager` - itself being an abstraction over different cache providers (e.g. IMemoryCache, Redis etc...) - prevent a multi-column implementation?

Comment: We dont give suggestions, how would you mark them as correct, they would be subjective, all of which are off topic for this site. You may want to read:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JohnB thanks for your feedback, I will rephrase the question.

Comment: i'm guessing modifying the schema is less work compared to option 2 and less risky.  i've always avoided combo-primary keys due to their hassle in the model layer